# how to set maximum volume? ios, audiounit

Tags: ios, iphone, volume, audiounit

My application looks like this:
[An iOS tone generator (an introduction to AudioUnits)](http://www.cocoawithlove.com/2010/10/ios-tone-generator-introduction-to.html)
also generates some signal. 
I want to set the max volume when app has been started. How to do it? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
float volume = 1.0f;
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:volume];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
[Music setVolume:0.3];
[Music play];
```

0.0 meaning volume off and 1.0 meaning max volume